# Push parameters to URL in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am making an angularjs app and I have to push user's company name to url.
For example, www.myapp.com/samsung or www.myapp.com/toyota.

My strategy to achieve was that first retrieve user's company information and get company's name and push the name to url using ui-router's $stateParams.

I am able to push the parameters, but it doesn't change the shape of url. The url just stays the same like www.myapp.com.

Is there any one who knows how to figure out this? Thanks

```
//main controller
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
 toParams = {company: $scope.user.company.nickname};//$scope.user.company.nickname contains company's name
});

//$stateProvider configuration
$stateProvider
.$state('home', {
  url: '/:company',
  ...
  ...
})
```

Comment: Where is the piece of code

Comment: You just want to append a String to the URL? Load a state? Make all states work with the dynamic String?

Comment: I am going to attach company name string to the url. Here are some examples. www.myapp.com/samsung. www.myapp.com/samsung/posts/create. www.myapp.com/samsung/posts/view/hello.

Answer (score 2):

UI-Router 1.0 and above can achieve this with an `onEnter` Transition Hook.

The hook checks if the parameter value is set or not.  If it's not set (is `null`), it redirects the transition to the same state but with the parameter value set.

```
  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'company', 
    url: '/:companyName', 
    params: { companyName: null }, // default to null
    onEnter: function ($transition$, $state, company)  {
      let params = $transition$.params();
      if (params.companyName === null) { // check if null. Get resolve and redirect
        return $state.target("company", { companyName: company.name });
      }
    },
    resolve: { 
      company: ($http) => 
          $http.get('company.json').then(resp => resp.data)
    },
    component: 'company',
  });
```

Here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aSJh6QyBUymKmaFNsOS8?p=info

Comment: Thanks it seems like the most promising answer! However, in my code, '$transition$' is not recognized. Does it come from other package other than ui-router?

Comment: It's in UI-Router 1.0 and above

Comment: Well... it seems like my original codes conflicts with the 1.0 version. I am kinda afraid of rebuilding all my codes to make it work. By the way, I really appreciate for your answer. It could be really good resource when I do the similar project in future!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is change the URL without reloading the page you can use:

```
var nameOfCompany = "toyota";
$location.url('/nameOfCompany');
```

`$location` is Angular's equvilant of `window.location` it can be used to observe and change the url without reloading. Check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for more info.

Comment: I am going to push the company name to all the other urls to dynamically.

Comment: @Supergentle ahh I misunderstood, as far as I am aware this isn't possible you will need either seperate states for each company name or the parameters for the url need to be given before routing to the state not after.

Comment: That's sad news... but I have to. Is there any other alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: As far as I am aware only multple states can achive this.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve what I wanted with ui-router 0.3x version. The code might look dirty, but it works as I imagined. Hope it could help someone who's finding the same feature.

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/:company',
    params: {company: null},
    templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
    onEnter: ['error', 'auth', '$state', 'company', '$stateParams', function (error, auth, $state,     company, $stateParams) {
        if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            return error.flash('Login is required.', 'login');
        }
        try {
            if ($stateParams.company === null || $stateParams.company !== company.nickname) {
                $state.go('home', {company: company.nickname});    
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('mop');
        }
    }],
    resolve: {
        company: ['auth', 'error', function (auth, error) {
            return auth.getMyCompany().then(function (res) {
                return res.data;
            }, function (err) {
                error.flash(401, 'login');
            });
        }],
    },
})
```